# Unable to send email using smtp gmail account

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, gmail, wamp

I am working on small project using wordpress on my local host using Wamp.
I am trying to send email using smtp using my gmail account but its not working and showing me boolean false when i am trying to send test email.

I tried this with by changing my host and it's working fine with already working host which is mail.name.com.
but its not working with gmail i think there must be some setting in gmail to enable smtp to send mail. I searched online but i am unable to find solution.

Answer (score 2):

step 1:
    please login your gmail account and click blow link:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

and Access for less secure apps pick ***Turn On***

Step 2:
    Disable second steps vitrification off in your gmail account.

also asking with your hosting provider gmail smtp sever all  allow or not In 
godaddy  you can not use gmail smtp server for sending mail.